# Following link before closing Bootstrap Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to close an alert **after** I click the link in it and we follow the link. What is happening is the alert is closing without following the link:

```
<div role="alert" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible">
    <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    A response has been updated. <a data-dismiss="alert" href="#main">Click here to view the update.</a>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require a lot of wired-up Javascript events if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to hook into the bootstrap event and it isn't that complicated. From documentation: [bootstrap alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts-events). It will require an id or appropriate selector for the alert.

**html**

```
<div role="alert" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" id="myAlert">
    <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    A response has been updated. <a data-dismiss="alert" href="#main">Click here to view the update.</a>
</div>
```

**js**

```
<script>
    $('#myAlert').on('closed.bs.alert', function () {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there was an attribute or such to enable this but this code is pretty minimal. I made one change. I navigated to the `href` value of the inner anchor tag like so: `$(alert).children().last("a").attr("href");`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be much of a general solution.  In my case, I have 5 links in the alert, and this solution doesn't help you know which one was clicked.