# Bootstrap alert link which both closes the alert and visits the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When you put both an `href` and a `data-dismiss="alert"` tag in a link in a Bootstrap alert, you don't get the expected behavior.  The expected behavior would be to open the link **and** close the alert.  I've seen it do one or the other, but never both.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<strong>Oh snap!</strong> Links in Bootstrap alerts are broken:
<a target="_blank" href="http://google.com" class="alert-link" data-dismiss="alert">Go to Google on new tab.</a>
</div>
```

How can I work around this bug?

This question is very similar to this: [Following link before closing Bootstrap Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699694/following-link-before-closing-bootstrap-alert), where a very specific answer was given for the case of a single link, which does not apply in my case.

Here's my alert, which hopefully clarifies what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4 - Multiple Links**

With multiple links you'll have to approach this problem the other way around. Placing an event listener on the parent & finding the child won't work because there is no reference pass as to which child, specifically was clicked.

Instead, place an event listener on each child link. Then you know specifically what was clicked. After it was clicked, you can trigger your `closed.bs.alert` manually on the parent, which is easy to find from the child.

```
$('.alert a').on('click', function (e) {
  $(e).parent().trigger('closed.bs.alert');
  window.open($(e.target).attr('href'));
});
```

BS4-ML: https://codepen.io/benjaminwfox/pen/vejLzz

**Bootstrap 4**

You can keep it a within the bootstrap paradigm by adding an event listener to each of your links. This is essentially the same thing as the answer in the question you linked, you just need to apply the listener based on a class selector rather than a specific ID. This way you don't need to do anything to handle the removal of the alert.:

```
$('.alert').on('closed.bs.alert', function (e) {
  console.log('Closed, alerted', $(e.target).children('a').attr('href'));
  window.open($(e.target).children('a').attr('href'));
})
```

BS4: https://codepen.io/benjaminwfox/pen/veXOEL

**Bootstrap 3**

Very similar to 4, but you'll have to use a custom tag for the URL:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Links in Bootstrap alerts are broken:
  <a data-dismiss="alert" data-href="http://www.msn.com" href="#">Go to Google on new tab.</a>
</div>

$('.alert').on('closed.bs.alert', function (e) {
  window.open($(e.target).children('a').attr('data-href'));
});
```

BS3: https://codepen.io/benjaminwfox/pen/bowQQy

**Non-Bootstrap Option**

If you wanted more of your own control over the whole process is to write your own JavaScript method to create the link behavior you're after. Implement it in the markup like so:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Links in Bootstrap alerts are broken:
  <a href="#" onclick="jsfunc(this, 'http://google.com')">Go to Google on new tab.</a>
</div>
```

Where `this` is a reference to the `<a>` tag, so you can do anything now to the `element` style, and the URL is passed as `p_url` so you can open the link:

```
function jsfunc(element, p_url) {
  element.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
  window.open(p_url);
}
```

NO BS: https://codepen.io/benjaminwfox/pen/GMjgbq

Comment: Your first option works perfectly!  The second did not work quite right (it hid the link, not the alert -- easily fixable by changing the line to element.parentElement.style.display = 'none';)  Regardless, the first option is totally sufficient for my needs.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad the first one worked! Updated the 2nd one anyway so it hides the correct element.

Comment: Bad news.  They work perfectly... in Bootstrap 4.  Now that I'm working with the real codebase on 3.3.X, it does not work.

Comment: That's some strange behavior right there. Off the top of my head it looks like the best option would be to use a custom tag, say, data-href so that bootstrap doesn't freak out. See if the updated answer works for you.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it -- you nailed it.

Comment: Sorry to have to come back AGAIN, but it's still not working right.  In my case I have multiple links in the alert, and your code always goes to the first link, even if it was another link that was clicked.  If I have an X to dismiss the alert, it follows the first link in that case too.

Comment: @BillHayden Updated with a new solution - I think this will solve both problems you mention since now only the links themselves will trigger an action.